# How to make a page stop responding while loading? (PHP)

Tags: php

Is it possible to end an PHP process from within PHP, to make it seem on the client side that it stopped responding, from a users perspective not from a technical point of view.

This is **not** a solution:

```
<?php
die();
?>
```

The idea is there is a file that's being downloaded and I don't want it ever to complete. Possible solution:

```
<?php
sleep(1000000000000000); //Or any really large number
?>
```

The downside is that this process will stay alive on the server side and you probably don't want that to happen.

Comment: you might want to add more information as to why `die` is not an option and what you would expect the client side to receive in that case.

Comment: This is going to be difficult I think. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Gordon `die()` is probably not an option because he seems to want to provoke a "connection aborted" event (whatever that looks like on protocol level, I don't know.). I doubt this is possible from within PHP, though, as it's Apache who is handling the request. The only idea that comes to mind is to crash the whole Apache process dealing with the request.

Comment: One idea comes to mind: `exec("sudo kill ".getmypid().");` (needless to say that is awful on so, so many levels)

Comment: @Pekka in other words: *It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.*

Comment: @Gordon yes, no doubt. I was just expressing my speculations :)

Comment: @Pekka A "don't try this at the office kids!" warning should be placed on that!

Comment: @Pekka that's exactly what I'm trying to do. If this is actually useful I have to figure that out but I want to see how browsers handle this when downloading files. Any solutions which use exec (or similar) would also be useful.

Comment: @Pekka I'll see if that works after lunch :)

Comment: @Pekka What about a really long sleep()?

Comment: @Joost okay, but it's really, really horrible practice to shoot down the running process. It should be used for testing purposes only, if even for that. Why not add that clarifying info into your question and see whether something comes up to do this cleanly.

Comment: @George that'll only cause a timeout, never an "aborted" I think!

Comment: A really long sleep would be a solution. I have thought about that, but I don't think that's very good on the server.

Comment: @Joost Nope, I don't think so. It will cause a timeout which is a different kind of error.

Comment: Personally, I'd be more worried about killing the process, if for no other reason than it's just awful.

Comment: @George absolutely, it's awful and it can even threaten the system's stability. But if the "aborted" state is what the OP wants, sleep is not going to help. I personally would support the "pull network cable" option as the healthiest one :)

Comment: I updated to OP to better reflect what I exactly want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to it and you're on a *nix system and have sufficient privileges, you could try killing the connection using a system call to `tcpkill`. Get the user's IP address and port (the incoming request will be on port 80, but the user will be on a uniquely identifiable port) and then kill the connection. Something like this:

```
<?php

$remotehost = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$remoteport = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];

$result = system("tcpkill host $remotehost port $remoteport");

echo($result ? "tcpkill worked" : "tcpkill didn't work");

?>
```

You could do the same thing with iptables, but I'd be real nervous about doing that. No better way to hose a box than ruining its firewall.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer no.

The best way I've found of testing systems how they handle broken connections is to physically pull out network cables from their sockets.

Answer (score 1):

To the question *"Is it possible to end an PHP process from within PHP, to make it seem on the client side that it stopped responding"* the answer is no. You won't be able to do that from within PHP, and I can't see how you could do that from outside PHP either.

Answer (score 0):

maybe `exit();` ?

Comment: "die — Equivalent to exit()" http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

Comment: very witty, but should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Other than shooting down the running process as outlined in the comments (which is horrible!) another idea that comes to mind - I am assuming this is for testing purposes and you have full control over the server - is to execute a shell script that activates a firewall, switches off the network adapter, or does something else that brings network activity to a grinding halt immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how long the client side will wait but this will hang for quite a while. It continually sends content for the browser to parse but the browser won't have anything to render.

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);

    while(true)
    {
        echo '<div></div>';
        flush();
    }
?>
```

As stated in your question, the down side is that the server will be running the script indefinitely. I presume that as soon as your script stops sending data, the browser isn't going to wait around.